# History.push a link to a new tab with react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I need to open a link to a new tab after doing some logic.
I have a button like this:

```
<Button
  onClick={handleSubmit}
>
  Preview
</Button>
```

with the handleSubmit() being:

```js
const history = useHistory();

const handleSubmit = () => {
  console.log("doing something");
  history.push("/some-link") 
}
```

As you can see, with my usecase it wouldn't make sense to use the `Link` component.

So, is there a way to push that link to a new tab, using only `history.push()`

Answer (score 71, accepted):

React-router's history is meant to be used just for the navigation of your application and some persistance. I can't see why you need to use it to open a new tab. I think you should use the window object for this.

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
  console.log("doing something");
  const win = window.open("/some-link", "_blank");
  win.focus();
}
```

UPDATE: Due to some comments that confirm that it is not neccesary to focus the new window we can make this solution even shorter, like:

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
  console.log("doing something");
  window.open("/some-link", "_blank");
}
```

Comment: I don't know why i limited my self to use only react-router, this would definitely work for me, thanks.

Comment: Did this work? I tried doing this but the context wasn't persisted in the new tab.

Comment: @Arpit Worked for me. Didnt use focus. onClick: () => {
        window.open("/some-link", "_blank");
      }

Comment: @Arpit It's important to note that the context data only exists in the current tab because it is stored in the memory used by it. So if you want to persist that information further than the current tab, you should write code to move that data to the localStorage, persisting it in your backend or something similar

Comment: history.push can pass this:----- pathname: '/link',
      search: value,
      state: { detail: statevalue }------ but window.open can not. I think so that why this question want to use history.push

Comment: @Tony yes, you are right. You can use the history object to pass some params to the new URL, but it will only work in the current tab, that's because react router's persistence is within the showing page. If you want to open a new tab, the history object will not be useful, because when you open a new tab all context and state is created from scratch. That's why you need to persist the data using other APIs to achieve the open new tab behavior

Comment: yes, you're right too, In this case I use window.open,focus pass params and use axios to fetch data in new tab.

Comment: It's blocked with safari and firefox

Comment: What do you mean @AmirAstaneh?

Comment: @MaCadiz Please test your code on safari and firefox browsers. It's detected as a popup and blocked.

Comment: @AmirAstaneh tested it and worked fine. Clean install of firefox and safari on mac

Comment: Can anyone clarify the use of `.focus` here? At least for my use case, I see no difference in the behavior with or without it (tested in Chrome and Firefox).
My understanding is that with or without the `.focus()` call, a new tab will open and also be navigated to.

Comment: @regs by the time as this answer was posted, some browsers wouldn't focus when using that method. I'm not able to test all major browsers at the time, but I can confirm that for chrome, firefox and edge for desktop is not neccesary.

Comment: @MaCadiz the question was a React Routing question and not a JS question. That's why we should stuck in response on React related solutions. With your JS solution state isn't possible to get carry on, without to save it to localStorage.

Comment: @lortschi that's because it wasn't not possible at that time (I think it's still not) to use the useHistory hook to achieve what OP was trying to do. If you read carefully, for them use case it didn't make sense to use the <Link> component, that would allow to open a new tab. In any case it's not possible (by security means) to trigger a new tab and magically passing information to it. You *must* use some form of webstorage, event or encoding data into the URL to pass information between tabs.

Answer (score 3):

If you simply want to open a new tab without any state transfer, you can just get the path using `useHref` hook ([Docs](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-href)). This is what the `<Link>` component internally [uses](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router-dom/index.tsx#L275). You can then open it in new tab using `window.open`. This would automatically add the basename etc for you.

```js
let href = useHref(to);
window.open(href, '_blank');
```